# Keras model with LSTM quantization aware training

Tags: keras, lstm, binary

I would like to run [quantization aware training](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/quantization/training_comprehensive_guide#setup_defaultdensequantizeconfig) with a keras model which has an LSTM layer. However, just the LSTM layer seems to not be supported. Alan Chiao seems to suggest [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/model-optimization/issues/376) that it is possible to use the Quantize Config to allow this layer to be used. However, I can't seem to make the right Quantize Config which allows for the use of the LSTM layer.

I attach below both the code for my model and the Quantize Config.

Could anyone confirm either

1. how to properly make a quantization aware model with an LSTM layer with keras
2. if LSTM quantization simply isn't supported with keras

Thanks for the feedback!

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers as L
quant_layer = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_annotate_layer
quant_apply = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_apply
quantize_scope = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_scope

######################  Simple Quantized Model   ####################

i = tf.keras.Input(shape=(32,32,1))
x = (L.Conv2D(1, (5, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'))(i)
x = L.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = L.Lambda(lambda q: K.squeeze(q, -1), name='squeeze_last_dim')(x)
x = quant_layer(L.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True),DefaultLSTMQuantizeConfig())(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x = L.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
o = L.Dense(12, activation='softmax')(x)

simple_model = Model(inputs=[i], outputs=[o])
simple_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=['sparse_categorical_crossentropy'], metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])

with quantize_scope(
    {'DefaultLSTMQuantizeConfig': DefaultLSTMQuantizeConfig}):
    simple_model_quant = quant_apply(simple_model)
     
simple_model_quant.summary()
```

```
##################### Quantize Config  #################
LastValueQuantizer = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantizers.LastValueQuantizer
MovingAverageQuantizer = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantizers.MovingAverageQuantizer

class DefaultLSTMQuantizeConfig(tfmot.quantization.keras.QuantizeConfig):
    # Configure how to quantize weights.
    def get_weights_and_quantizers(self, layer):
        return [(layer.layer.recurrent_kernel, LastValueQuantizer(num_bits=8, symmetric=True, narrow_range=False, per_axis=False))]

    # Configure how to quantize activations.
    def get_activations_and_quantizers(self, layer):
        return [(layer.activation, MovingAverageQuantizer(num_bits=8, symmetric=False, narrow_range=False, per_axis=False))]

    def set_quantize_weights(self, layer, quantize_weights):
      # Add this line for each item returned in `get_weights_and_quantizers`
      # , in the same order
        layer.kernel = quantize_weights[0]

    def set_quantize_activations(self, layer, quantize_activations):
      # Add this line for each item returned in `get_activations_and_quantizers`
      # , in the same order.
        layer.activation = quantize_activations[0]

    # Configure how to quantize outputs (may be equivalent to activations).
    def get_output_quantizers(self, layer):
        return []

    def get_config(self):
        return {}
```

Comment: execuse me,I want to know `x = L.Lambda(lambda q: K.squeeze(q, -1), name='squeeze_last_dim')(x)` this line means what in code？